# java rpc in for loop

Tags: java, loops, rpc

I have an rpc call in a for-loop to receive a list of elements. The problem I have is that the return statement of the method is called before the for-loop is finished. So there a possibility to force the return statement to wait for the loop to finish?

```
public List<SOMETHING> getList() {
     List<SOMETHING> list = ...;
     for (A FEW REPETITIONS) {
          RPC-CALL() {
            public void onSuccess(List<SOMETHING> result) {
                 list.addAll(result);
            }
          }
     }

     return list;
}
```

Comment: What RPC mechanism are you using ? Are these asynchronous calls ?

Comment: if your rpc call is being executed in a separate thread/process, you need to wait accordingly. can you put more code/make it more clear?

Comment: there is no return statement in your for loop. how can it return before the for loop is completed?

Comment: I'm using asynchronous calls, and therefore the for-loop is finished before the rpc calls or finished

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use  [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html), you can initialize the counter to number of rpc calls you are making. Decrease the count on getting reply for your rpc calls and wait for the replies using countDownLatch.await()

Comment: I'm using java gwt, and when I simply create a new CountDownLatch object I get a com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.InternalCompilerException: Failed to get JNode

Comment: It looks like GWT does not support any synchronization in client. In that case you may need to avoid returning value from this method but instead have the caller provide some actionListener kind of handler that you will call with all processed results.